# Dropzone.js : Show alert if request is taking more time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I have used dropzone.js to come up with a file upload module. This library is great and it is pretty flexible too.

However, I have got stuck with one condition. I try to upload say 100 files at bulk to a rails server. If there is a network issue , the ajax call takes a lot of time to respond back.

During the time the ajax call is alive, I want to give an alert saying "Network is slow. Please wait" if the call is exceeding some specified amount of time to respond back.

Is this possible?

Please help.

Comment: Start a timer when the request starts, when the timer ends show a message. If the request completes before the timer ends, clear the timer. You haven't shown any code, so I can't really help you with the specifics.

Comment: When u say a timer, how to implement that in JS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Hi ..I included the setTimeOut funnction to implement this.
However, the problem is setTimeOut wont call the registered function as async process.. and my all other processes are stuck untill setTimeOut returns....